# override angular ui-router for links to page anchors

Tags: angularjs, anchor, angular-ui-router

I have links to anchors on my page (a href="#idea").  ui-router obviously overrides them.  Is there a way to use both in harmony?  Thank you.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2880f2f2c9f91b0b695f#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you aren't supposed to use it on a `href` this way, instead you should add it like the following:

```
<a href="" ng-click="gotoAnchor()">...</a>
```

You can see an example of this at the bottom of the `$anchorScroll` API [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Comment: Thanks for this aswer Bricktop. Your solution works to a certain extent though. What if I want to use my anchor content as a popup/modal, without using $modal or the UI bootstrap library which in my opinion is still a headache for me to wrap my head around?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you use case. If you want to feed content to your anchor and a modal then you could do that much more easily through your controller which would feed data to both.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine ui-router with anchor tag, I solved my problem using this code

```
<a ui-sref="routename({'#': 'ownerfeatures'})">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had similar problem with anchors.

Since I want to go on using regular HTML syntax (href="#may-hash") I've made a directive which looks if a link is an anchor and if yes perform scroll operations. See detailed code :

```
/**
 * Ressource : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll
 */
.directive('a', ['$location', '$anchorScroll', function ($location, $anchorScroll) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs)
        {
            // href should be defined and not empty
            if(typeof attrs.href!=='undefined' && attrs.href.length > 0)
            {
                // href should be an anchor
                if(attrs.href.substring(0, 1) === '#')
                {
                    elem.on('click', function (e)
                    {
                        // if current hash is different from requested hash
                        // then set new hash
                        // no need to call $anchorScroll() 
                        // since scroll is auto if you've not used $anchorScroll.disableAutoScrolling()
                        if ( '#' + $location.hash() !== attrs.href)
                        {
                            $location.hash(attrs.href);
                        }
                        // if hash is the same, force scroll
                        else
                        {
                            $anchorScroll();
                        }

                    });
                }
            }

        }
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do this is this way
say you are on state `app.state1.child` and your anchor tag is `#list`, so say that you `a` tag use this code

```
<a ui-sref="app.state1.child#list">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old topic but always get stuck looking a better solution to do the anchoring in my apps.

Today I was looking to scroll in the same page and tested a lot of differents solutions. Most of the time this one is the general recommendation:

```
<a ui-sref="routename({'#': 'ownerfeatures'})">Link</a>
```

The problem with this one is works to transition to a new state and go to the anchor but doesn't work well if you want to just scroll in the same page, because it only works the first click.

Then I realize that the use of `$anchorScroll` should be great for this and I made this directive maybe can help someone. Note I didn't use location.hash, because I don't want to add the hash to my address bar and also there where some situations in my flow that make the screen scroll when not required.

```
 function anchorScroll($anchorScroll){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        target: '=anchorScroll'
      },
      link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
        element.bind('click', function(event) {
          console.log(scope.target)
          $anchorScroll(scope.target);
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

But the also there is a very simplest way, just using `$anchorScroll` in the template. In your controller:

```
$scope.anchorScroll = $anchorScroll;
```

And in the view:

```
<a href="" ng-click="anchorScroll('nameOfTheAnchor')">Scroll to ID</a>
```